# Link_to its edit path after searching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I get my search result from multiple models.

And I want to provide each result with a link to its `show page`

Each result is an instance of its model.

How to achieve this among multiple models, it should be done in dynamically,

Because the models will grow.

For example, the results will come from `model Car, Plane, ...`

If the result is from Car , I should write  `link_to edit_car_path(<RESULT>)` in the view

If from Plane, `link_to edit_plane_path(<RESULT>)` in the view

Can it link_to the edit page view the record itself, without view route helper ?

Because the results are composited of many models, so their routes are differ.

### Update

Comment: provide an example of what you have in place already, show us what you are doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what's stopping you doing something like this

```
<% @record.each do |r| %>
 <%= link_to 'My Link', r %>
<% end %>
```

So here you are just iterating through your collection of results and then linking to the object itself

Comment: what do you think it would be based on my previous answer?